# Send Slack Message Flow Core Action Not Working on Asynchronous Path

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity, administration, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

I have created a Flow with a Send Slack Message action via the Salesforce for Slack app when any of the following fields are updated on the Opportunity:

- Amount
- Stage
- Close Date

My Flow is executing the Send Slack Message action on an asynchronous path, and works when debugging. However, when I activate the Flow and update any of the above fields on an opportunity, no message posts to Slack. I checked the Time-Based Workflow but there is no queue. Any ideas as to why it's not sending the message to slack?

Answer (score 0):

The following could be reasons for not working

- Check CRUD/FLS for the user executing the flow
- Check if the user executing the action is properly authorized to the Slack workspace.

Comment: Hi Mohith, thank you for your reply. Are you able to point me in the direction of documentation to check this? I thought I had enabled permissions and authorized the user to Slack workspace but not sure.

Comment: @ChristinaChan Can you share the screenshot from your flows showing all of the configuration you have so I could better answer your query?